# How can I sort a list of dates using sort(unique)

Tags: sorting, google-sheets

In google sheets I have a form that populates my sheet.  In my sheet I use the sort(unique) function to create a dropdown list.  How can I sort that dropdown list to show latest date at top of the list.

My formula currently is =sort(unique(MyResponsePage!AA2:AA)) and it will show today's date at the bottom the list for my dropdown list that I use on a dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
=sort(unique(MyResponsePage!AA2:AA),1,false)
```

[sort()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150)